# How to use data templates in ASP.NET razor syntax

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am working on asp.net project and I want to make a page that have something like this :

[image]

I want to put the images in the previous picture in something like a data templates and I want to show the pages numbers in that way .... 
Is there a good article or tutorial that can help me to perform this ... because I'm a beginner in this field ....

Comment: If you can't explain what exactly you're looking for, it's hard to find it. What part are you having trouble with? Do you know what a `DisplayTemplate` is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume view models:

```
public class ProjectVM
{
  public String ImageUrl { get; set; }
  public String ProjectName { get; set; }
}
public class IndexVM
{
  // nuget> Install-Package PagedList
  public IPagedList<ProjectVM> projects { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(Int32 page = 1)
  {
    IndexVM model = new IndexVM
    {
      Projects = projectService.GetProjects().ToPagedList(page, 6)
    };
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Then your views:

**~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ProjectVM.cshtml**

```
@model ProjectVM
@* Or however you display it... *@
<div class="span4">
  <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" />
  <p>@Model.Name</p>
</div>
```

**~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@mode IndexVM
@* Or however you display it... *@
<div class="content">
  <section>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>All projects</h1>
      <div class="paging">
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Projects, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
      </div>
   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Projects)
</div>
```

Example project found [on GitHub](https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/question-19220684)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will find it in awesome book Pro ASP.NET MVC 4
on page 101 (razor) and 183 (paging). It is the must read book!

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Adam-Freeman/dp/1430242361/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1381864006&sr=8-1&keywords=asp.net+mvc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361)